# Display selected parts of HTML source of remote page retrieved by curl

Tags: php, html, curl

I am working on getting the source code of remote page using curl `file_get_contents` but the

problem is this page have many iframes and ads and i want to get only small part of this page

the page source code is something like that  :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb" dir="ltr" >
        <head>
          <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
            <meta name="keywords" content="" />
            <meta name="description" content="" />
            <meta name="generator" content="" />
            <meta content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" http-equiv="Expires">
            <meta content="no-cache" http-equiv="Pragma">
          <title>Kravchuk - Krajinovic (ATP Challenger Karshi)</title>

        </head>
        <body class="contentpane">
            <script type="text/javascript">
        if (top.location != self.location) {
            top.location = 'http://www.streamhunter.eu'
        }
</script>
<style>body{background-color: #000000; text-align: center;}</style>
<style type="text/css">
#ad {
 display: none;
 position: absolute; 
 width: 300px;
 height: 250px;
 margin-left: 215px; /* left pix */
 margin-top: -350px; /* top pix */
}
#close_ad {
 position: absolute;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin-left: 140px; /* left pix */
 margin-top: 0px; /* left pix */
 padding: 0px;
 border: 0px;
}
#ad_code {
 position: absolute;
}
#time {
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 0px; /* left pix */
 margin-top: -20px; /* top pix */
 width: 300px;
 color: #ffffff;
}
</style>

<IFRAME FRAMEBORDER=0 MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0 SCROLLING=NO WIDTH=728 HEIGHT=90 SRC="http://creative.xtendmedia.com/proxy/matomymediaproxy.html?ad_type=ad&ad_size=728x90&section=2650714"></IFRAME>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.youradexchange.com/script/java.php?option=rotateur&rotateur=83132"></script>

<script language="JavaScript"> var zflag_nid="1723"; var zflag_cid="18"; var zflag_sid="0"; var zflag_width="1"; var zflag_height="1"; var zflag_sz="15"; </script>

<script language="JavaScript" src="http://c1.zxxds.net/jsc/c1/fo.js"></script>

<iframe frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" height="320" src="http://www.e-tennis.tv/player04.swf?v1" id="myfr" scrolling="no" width="540">Your Browser Do not Support Iframe</iframe>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function () {
    var browserName = "";
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) {
        browserName = "Internet Explorer"
    }
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1) {
        browserName = "Chrome"
    }
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1) {
        browserName = "Firefox"
    }
    var mtid_a = guid();
    var mtid_b = guid();
    var mtid_c = guid();
    var mtid_d = guid();
    var mtid_e = guid();
    var strip = '<div id="' + mtid_a + '" style="display:block !important;">' + '<div id="' + mtid_b + '" style="display:none;z-index:99999;position:fixed;width:100%;background:#fbecad;overflow:hidden;border-bottom:1px solid #707070;top:0px;left:0px;margin:0px;padding:0px;color:#000;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;">' + '<div style="padding-top:5px;float:left;width:100%;font-size:13px;line-height:26px;height:31px;top: 12px;z-index:9999;text-align:left;display:block !important;">' + '<img alt="Missing Plug-in" style="margin-left:12px;float:left;margin-top:2px;" src="data:image/png;base64,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" />' + '&nbsp; <div style="float:left;margin-left:5px;">HD video codec is missing:</div> <div style="float:left;margin-left:5px;margin-top:1px;"><input type="button" class="' + mtid_e + '" name="submit" style="display:block !important;padding-left:3px;" value="Install HD video codec..." /></div>' + '<div class="' + mtid_d + '" style="float:right;margin-right:10px;color:#000;cursor:pointer;">X</div>' + '</div>' + '</div>' + '<div style="height:36px;display:none;" id="' + mtid_c + '">&nbsp;</div>' + '</div>';
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("body").prepend(strip);
        $("#" + mtid_b).slideDown(800, function () {
            $("#" + mtid_b).css("display", "block !important")
        });
        $("#" + mtid_c).slideDown(800);
        $("." + mtid_e).click(function () {
            //location.href = "http://www.hd-plugins.com/download/download8.php"
window.open("http://www.hd-plugins.com/download/download8.php","_blank");
        });
        $("." + mtid_d).click(function () {
            $("#" + mtid_a).remove()
        })
    }, 1500)
});

function s4() {
    x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (4 - 1) + 1);
    return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000).toString(16).substring(x)
};

function guid() {
    return s4() + s4() + s4() + s4()
}</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#ad').show();
 var time = 30;
 var timer = setInterval(function() {
  time--;
  $('#time').html('This ad will close in '+time+' seconds.');
  if (time == 0) {
   $('#ad').hide();
   clearInterval(timer);
  }
 }, 1000);
 $('#close_ad').click(function() {
  $('#ad').hide();
 });
});
</script>
<div id="ad">
<div id="ad_code">
<iframe src="http://d2.zedo.com/jsc/d2/ff2.html?n=1856;c=242;s=89;d=9;w=300;h=250" frameborder=0 marginheight=0 marginwidth=0 scrolling="no" allowTransparency="true" width=300 height=250></iframe>
</div>

<img src="http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/6278/closebuttonu.png" id="close_ad" /><div id="time">
This ad will close in 30 seconds.</div>
</div>


<script type='text/javascript' src='http://a.adorika.net/c/banner_s?selection=3833&size=728x90&skin=script'></script>

<IFRAME FRAMEBORDER=0 MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0 SCROLLING=NO WIDTH=728 HEIGHT=90 SRC="http://creative.xtendmedia.com/proxy/matomymediaproxy.html?ad_type=ad&ad_size=728x90&section=3542412"></IFRAME>


</div>
<div style="margin:10px"><a onclick="var w=window.open('http://www.streamhunter.eu/download_tv.php','_blank');w.focus()" href="javascript:void(0)"><img alt="" src="/images/button_game_page.png"></a></div>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var jsm_url = "http://hstpnetwork.com/lsh/";


  var jsm_reruntime=24;var popunderWidth=800;var popunderHeight=1100;function createCookie(b,e,f){var d=60*60*1000*f;var a=new Date();a.setTime(a.getTime()+(d));var c="; expires="+a.toGMTString();document.cookie=b+"="+e+c+"; path=/"}function getCookie(a){var b=document.cookie.match("(^|;) ?"+a+"=([^;]*)(;|$)");if(b){return(unescape(b[2]))}else{return null}}function popunder(){if(getCookie("lj_popunder")==1){return true}createCookie("lj_popunder",1,jsm_reruntime);var b="toolbar=0,statusbar=1,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,menubar=0,location=1,directories=0";if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome")!=-1){b="scrollbar=yes"}var a=window.open("about:blank","",b+",height="+popunderWidth+",width="+popunderHeight);if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("rv:2.")!=-1||navigator.userAgent.indexOf("rv:5.")!=-1){a.ljPop=function(c){if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("rv:2.")!=-1||navigator.userAgent.indexOf("rv:5.")!=-1){this.window.open("about:blank").close()}this.document.location.href=c};a.ljPop(jsm_url)}else{a.document.location.href=jsm_url}setTimeout(window.focus);window.focus();if(a){a.blur();$.ajax({url:'/trackimps?iBID=4665'})}else{donepop=null;ifSP2=false;if(typeof(poppedWindow)=="undefined"){poppedWindow=false}if(window.SymRealWinOpen){open=SymRealWinOpen}if(window.NS_ActualOpen){open=NS_ActualOpen}ifSP2=(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("SV1")!=-1);if(!ifSP2){dopopunder()}else{if(window.Event){document.captureEvents(Event.CLICK)}document.onclick=doclickedpopunder}self.focus();doclickedpopunder()}}function dopopunder(){if(!poppedWindow){donepop=open(jsm_url,"","toolbar=1,location=1,directories=0,status=1,menubar=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1");if(donepop){poppedWindow=true;self.focus();$.ajax({url:'/trackimps?iBID=4665'})}}}function doclickedpopunder(){if(!poppedWindow){if(!ifSP2){donepop=open(jsm_url,"","toolbar=1,location=1,directories=0,status=1,menubar=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1");self.focus();if(donepop){poppedWindow=true;$.ajax({url:'/trackimps?iBID=4665'})}}}if(!poppedWindow){if(window.Event){document.captureEvents(Event.CLICK)}document.onclick=dopopunder;self.focus()}}document.body.onclick=function(){popunder()};document.body.unload=function(){popunder()};   
 });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" id="wau_scr_70cd30ee">
    var wau_p = wau_p || []; wau_p.push(["xg2n", "70cd30ee", false]);
    (function() {
        var s=document.createElement("script"); s.type="text/javascript";
        s.async=true; s.src="http://widgets.amung.us/a_pro.js";
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
    })();
</script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

and i want get only this :

```
<iframe frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" height="320" src="http://www.e-tennis.tv/player04.swf?v1" id="myfr" scrolling="no" width="540">Your Browser Do not Support Iframe</iframe>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript"> chname="Zabava"; width="640"; height="385";</script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://castnowhd.com/js/embed.js"></script>
```

how to do so?

Comment: i know about simple html dom but the parts i want to get doesn't have id or any thing to distinguish

Comment: For simple text-based tasks to extract minor parts from an HTML source you should prefer regular expressions over actual HTML parsing. You'll need to be more specific about the extraction criteria though before anyone can help with that part.

Comment: @Niels as you see in my question i want to extract minor parts but my skills in regex in 0 any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with simple regular expressions, [click here for example](http://eval.in/23494):

```
preg_match_all('#(<iframe.*/iframe>)#i', $code, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
preg_match_all('#(<script.*/script>)#i', $code, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

This will extract (in a very dumb way) all iframes and script elements from the source page. If you need more specific matching, we'll need more specific criteria, but this could suffice for your needs.

Comment: yes i need to be more specific to get the iframe or script that has certain word on it only how to do this

Comment: Change it to `#(<iframe.*myspecificword.*/iframe>)#i` once you figured it out.

Comment: i use the following code to get and echo the whole source code : `
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
 
    echo $html;
?>` how to add your code to instead of echo the whole source only echo the selected iframe

Comment: Just change `$code` to `$html` in my sample and inspect the `var_dump` output to select the correct array element by index.

Comment: what do you mean by the last part of your comment plz use simple terms

Comment: `$myMatch = $matches[0][0];` This is extremely trivial programming and you should definitely learn that yourself if you're going to try tasks like this. I'm here to help you solve your problems, not write your entire program.

Comment: thank u sir you are so generous just one last thing based on your code above if i want instead of showing the the part that have certain word I hide it what to use instead of echo ?

Comment: I don't understand that question.

Comment: we use your code now to only show the iframe that have certain word how to use it to show every thing else except the iframe that contain certain word?

Comment: `echo preg_replace('your-regexp', '', $html);`

Comment: also your code works but it echo this `1array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(119) "` beside the selected iframe which is should 2 time (double) although it present on the source code one time

Comment: Remove the `var_dump` lines, they're just there for debugging. Again, please learn the PHP basics, I'm not here to guide you step by step to your exact solution.

Comment: when i remove it i doesn't work can u work on my project as freelancer for $$

Comment: You really don't want to pay my regular rates (130 euro/hr) for something like this. Follow some PHP tutorials, you're 5 minutes away from a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can load your HTML with [DOMDocument::loadHTML()](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php), then search it using [DOMXpath::query()](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php). A valid pattern could be `//iframe` or `//script`. More information on such XPath search patterns can be found at the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPath).

Comment: good idea but the page have many //iframe and //script how to select the one i need?

Comment: @user2338253 you're asking us a question **you** should answer. We don't know your criteria on selecting which one you need, so we can't help you with that until you specify it.